# Ошибка при установке Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

Взялся за изучение фреймворка Meteor.js. Установил node.js, как сказано в офф инструкции на сайте meteor. Потом проверил через node -v и npm -v что все установлено и работает. После в консоли ввел команду на установку npm install -g meteor. И тут появилась ошибка, прогуглив которую ответа не нашел. Вот не полный текст ошибки из консоли. win 10.
'
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'meteor@2.11.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '<=14.x', npm: '<=6.x' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v19.8.1', npm: '9.5.1' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
'

Comment: вы не понимаете смысл логического оператора «меньше или равно» (`<=`)? или вам не понятно, что 19 — больше, чем 14, а 9 — больше, чем 6?

Comment: проще говоря "версия node.js не подходит для Meteor.js". установите nvm и на нём 14 версию ноды или не изучайте метеор.